# Storing video online for android app videoview

Tags: android, video, youtube, android-videoview

I have a `VideoView` in my android activity, I want to stream a video into it. My question is where is the best place to store it; I'd place it on youtube but I read that I would have to use the Youtube API rather than `VideoView` since there wouldn't be a direct link available, only a link to the page displaying the video. The online server I use has a limit of `10MB` for a file so that won't work either. I want the video to load reasonably fast and not have any major issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few options, from hosting it on your own server at one end of the scale to using a hosting service like brightcove, vimeo etc at the other end.

If you want good playback performance for your video there are two keys things you need (which YouTube or Brightcove etc will provide as standard):

- a content delivery network - this delivers your content speedily where ever your users are, and does not depend on your own servers location, computing power, bandwidth etc
- Adaptive bit rate streaming - this allows the client (e.g. the browser) switch between bit rate streams depending on the network connection and conditions. So if the network is good it will use a high bit rate stream, support HD for example, and if the network is bad it will use a lower bitrate/quality and it can switch between streams as the network conditions change.

If you do want to go your own way then using amazon S3 and it's CDN service, Cloudfront, is worth looking at, even if just to see an example of how it can be done. There is an up to date guide here, but you can probably find others with a quick search for 'video S3 cloud front':

- http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/delivering-hls-with-amazon-cloudfront/